# Unhandled exception at 0x771515ee Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0049f904

Tags: c++

I need to allocate a very large array is there a way to allocate an array without this types of errors? note that I have 8 GB of memory without using vector
this is exactly the error

```
Unhandled exception at 0x771515ee in __ Microsoft C++ exception:
 std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0049f904..
```

and this is a chunk of my code

```
#include<cstdlib>
int main()
{
  size_t arraySize =1024*1024*1024;
  int *a= new int[arraySize];
  for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
  {
    a[i] = 3;
  } 
  return 0; 
}
```

/* Thanks guys the solution for my problem is to create a new solution platform with x64 bit operation*/

Comment: Those look like 32bit pointers (i.e. the kind that can only hold 4G distinct addresses).

Comment: Are you on 32- or 64-bit Windows?

Comment: ...and are you compiling for 64-bit operation?

Comment: @yasser Rather than editing the question to repeat the answers, you should accept the answer that is most helpful. Please read the [faq]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to allocate a 4GB block in a 32 bit process. That's not possible. You are limited to somewhere between 2GB and 4GB addressable space, but in reality much less will be available in a single contiguous block.

If you really need such a large block in a single array then you'll want to switch to a 64 bit process. Reconsidering your algorithm is likely to be the best solution.

Comment: He's trying to allocate 1GB, not 4GB.

Comment: @DeadMG `sizeof(int)==4`, on Windows

Comment: I am using core I7 it is 64 bit

Comment: Your process is a 32 bit process. Use a 64 bit process and the code will work.

Answer (score 0):

A 32bit address space probably does not have 1GB of continuous memory available (and definitely not 4GB). You must compile for x64.

Comment: Actually this attempts to allocate 4GB so no amount of chunking is going to help on 32 bit

Comment: The Visual C++ Standard Library's `deque` should be avoided if at all possible because it has abysmal performance characteristics:  [it performs roughly like an array of pointers to elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5607710/151292).